# Global climate change

Tags: climate-change, desert

We all know that global climate change is becoming a big real change that is affecting the world's ecosystems and life cycles.

Will global climate change affect the hot areas of the world or deserts like the UAE, Oman, Sahara desert etc.?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_effects_of_global_warming